# The downvote button doesn't give the right error message

Tags: feature-request, reputation, voting, down-votes

I don't have enough reputation in the Stackoverflow community. So whenever I try to downvote a public post, there is a blue message which says:

> Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 125 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

However this is confusing because I can still upvote posts. I am just not allowed to downvote. This message should instead say:

*Thanks for the feedback! **Down**votes cast by those with less than 125 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.*

This is just a small thing to change.

Comment: This has message been changed [a few days ago](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326060/change-the-wording-of-thank-you-for-your-feedback-when-a-user-below-125-re/327213#327213). It seems that the same message template is used for both up- and downvotes.

Comment: @Glorfindel That is right. The same message was displayed for upvotes when I didn't have enough reputation to upvote. I think there needs to be a separate template for the downvote button.